# Wowza not destroy stream, not destroy rtsp session

Tags: stream, rtsp, wowza

I stream to wowza by RTSP, and--after I finish streaming--I get in wowza log that:

`stream unpublish <stream>
 stream destroy
 rtsp session destroy`

but sometimes I get

`stream unpublish <stream>`

I have developer licence so on third same stream I get message:

`*** Hit license limit for publishing streams. Publishing stream is stopped. ***`

Can somebody tell in which case stream not destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

The `destroy` is triggered by a client disconnect while the `unpublish` is server-side.

You are most likely using `<StreamType>rtp-live</StreamType>` as type in `Application.xml`. In this case Wowza automatically publishes your stream when a client demands the stream and shuts it down on a disconnect.

There are two things you can try:

1. put your RTSP stream in `StartupStreams.xml` so it's started by the server at startup.
2. change the `<StreamType>` to `live` and write a custom module using the `MediaCaster` API to publish your stream manually. In this case the stream is not automatically unpublished on a disconnect, although you need to see what happens if the source stream dies.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem. During publish I create another ILiveStreamRecorder, when segment finishes I stop recording. Maybe, wowza not close or not destroy this recorder or etc., so rtsp session is not destroyed.